# JQuery UI dialog with form loaded dynamically gives problems in IE8

Tags: jquery, user-interface, internet-explorer-8, dialog

This problem only occurs in IE8, otherwise works fine in Chrome, FF, etc. The problem is that I am trying to break a large project into smaller modules by having the HTML files loaded as required. One of the HTML file has a dialog with a HTML form as its content. The following is code from the parent file:

```
   $('#login').click(function(){ 
        $('#login_dialog').load('html/login_dialog.html', function() {
              $("#login_dialog").dialog("open");
        });
   });
```

The dialog code is in the login_dialog.html file. On click, it loads the file and does the rest. Very simple and it works as expected except in IE8. The error reported in IE8 is

```
cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'
```

Now if the entire login_dialog.html file is copied in the parent file rather than having it loaded dynamically, then all's well even in IE8. Any ideas on fixing this? I tried the dialog_var = $(#login_dialog).dialog({....}); and then followed by dialog_var.dialog("open") as suggested in another post in this forum. That did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

IE typically is too fast with executing subsequent statements

Try

```
$('#login').click(function(){ 
    $('#login_dialog').load('html/login_dialog.html', function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
          $("#login_dialog").dialog("open");
       },100);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried it even by increasing the timeout but to no avail. Reports the same error but your suggestion is certainly helpful as it eliminates one possibility.